# Access set of previous rows in python mask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I need to delete the dates that collide between their start and end periods.

To do this, I will buy the index with 'stop', that is, `if index[-1] >= stop[:0]` eliminates the date, that is, all the indices that are prior to the previous stop

The table is like this

[image]

And the filter that i tried

```
table= table[table['index'][-1]>=table['stop'][:0]]
```

Note: I know that I put the index as a column and not as an index, but ignore that, in my code I have it as a column

Edit: I tried to with the filter
`table= table[table['index']>=table['stop'][:0]]`
but it doesn't work either, returns:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: What's the problem with the filter you tried?

Comment: Returns to me KeyError: -1

Comment: help, i dont find the anwser